# Compute and initialize external configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following properties defined in `application.properties`

```
test.key1=value_1,value_2
test.key2=value_3,value_4
```

and retrieve the properties as

```
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
class CustomPropLoader extends HashMap<String, List<String>>> {}
```

and I can use the above to inject into the required objects.
However my requirement is to

> inverse the above map and then make it available across all the
> objects in the container to enable lookup by hashmap keys rather than searching all the entries

and I tried to do the below:

```
@Service
class PropFetcher {

private CustomPropLoader customPropLoader;
private Map<String,String> transposedMap;

void PropFetcher(@Autowired CustomPropLoader customPropLoader){
this.customPropLoader = customPropLoader;
this.transposedMap = transposeValues(); // logic to transpose the hashmap entries
}
```

This seems to work, however is less testable as the transposedMap could not be mocked nor injected.
Is there a better solution to inverse the values during bean initialization, which is unit testable too ?

PS : I don't prefer @PostConstruct feature.

Thanks

Comment: *lookup by hashmap keys rather than searching all the entries* What does this actually mean, specifically?

Comment: I need to transpose the map initialised from prop file and make it available for injection.